# How to return results from SQL SELECT raw Query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I have a method in my controller class that is supposed to return the results from a raw SQL query inside the method. The problem is I can't pull return more than one column result to the list in a query that is supposed to return multiple column results.

I know that the problem has to do with how I am adding to the results list during the Read, but I am unsure how to structure this properly to return multiple values.

Here is my current method:

```
public IActionResult Search ([FromRoute]string input)
{
    string sqlcon = _iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("StringName").Value;

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlcon))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()
                             {
                                   CommandText = "SELECT u.UserID, u.User FROM [dbo].[Users] u WHERE User = 'Value';",
                                   CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                                   Connection = con
                             })
        {
            con.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }

                con.Close();

                return Ok(new Search(results));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The SQL query is supposed to return the `UserID` and User based on the entered User, however, only the User gets returned here.

Does anyone know what I am missing to return multiple column names for this SQL query and method? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, I can't use a stored procedure here, I do not have permission to create an SP on this database.

Comment: *I can't use a stored procedure here, since I am talking to a remote DB* ?!?!?!? Care to explain?? Just because you're talking to a remote server doesn't exclude the possibility of using a stored procedure, IMHO. ....

Comment: What DB server are you talking to?

Comment: Sorry, allow me to better clarify, the database I am talking to exists on a remote server. And I have not been given permission to create Stored Procedures in this database.

Comment: Well, you're only reading one value from each record: `reader.GetString(0)`  And you're adding it to a list of strings.  Did you mean to get more strings from `reader` in each record?  What happens when you try that?  Are they all going to be added to the same list of results?  That is, do you really just want to return a `List<string>` and let the calling code figure out which values are associated with each other?  Seems like returning a list of some object with two properties would make more sense here.

Comment: `And I have not been given permission to create Stored Procedures in this database`  That's the relevant reason you can't use stored procedures.  Being a remote server isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class for the results of the Query

```
public class ClassForResults(){
    public int UserID { get; set; };
    public string User { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Search ([FromRoute]string input)
{
    string sqlcon = _iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("StringName").Value;

    List<ClassForResults> results = new List<ClassForResults>();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlcon))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()
                             {
                                   CommandText = "SELECT u.UserID, u.User FROM [dbo].[Users] u WHERE User = 'Value';",
                                   CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                                   Connection = con
                             })
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ClassForResults result = new ClassForResults();
                    result.UserID = reader.GetInt(0);
                    result.User = reader.GetString(1);
                    results.Add(result);
                }

                con.Close();

                return Ok(new Search(results));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should get me going in the right direction. Thank you!